# Cannot add ServiceActivity to CRM Dynamics solution

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm trying to customise the Service Activity entity which appears on the Service Calendar in Dynamics CRM 2013.

When I open a Solution and click Add Existing, I can see the entity in the list, but when I click Ok I receive a generic error message "An error has occurred.."

There is no JS appearing in the browser console, nothing in the System Log, and nothing in the CRM log. I've tried this on two separate CRM instances.

I'm beginning to think the entity falls into the "you cannot customise this prebuilt MS entity" category, but I cannot find any MS documentation to support this view.

Has anyone been able to customise the entity? And is there any other log location I should be checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would bet you are using Chrome or Firefox and not Internet Explorer. Will you give it a try in IE?

As a rule of thumb, I only do customizations in IE... unless they don't work in IE, and then I resort to Chrome :)

Comment: Unbelievable! I've seen the drawbacks from using a non IE browser in the Report Wizard or Form editor...Seems like the problem is everywhere. Thank you.